# Make say 'doc' is up to date with the doc folder empty (Makefile C++)

Tags: makefile

When I want to generate my doc with a makefile and with doxygen, I have this output :

```
make: 'doc' is up to date.
```

But my doc can't be up to date when the doc folder is empty !

Can you say me whyt I have this message ?

*(The project where the makefile is, is a C++ project)*

In below you can find the makefile and the Doxyfile.

#### MakeFile

```
CC = clang++
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++14
HDIR = include

CLASS = obj/Handyman.o obj/Saw.o obj/ScrewDriver.o obj/Hammer.o
INTERFACE = obj/ToolScrewing.o obj/ToolBreak.o obj/ToolCutting.o
ABSTRACT = obj/Tool.o
FACTORY = obj/ToolFactory.o

compile: bin/main
    ./bin/main

bin/main: obj/main.o ${CLASS} ${ABSTRACT} ${INTERFACE} ${FACTORY}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $^

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o $@ $< -I ${HDIR}

doc:
    doxygen Doxyfile

clean: 
    rm obj/*.o
    rm bin/*

cleanDoc:
    rm doc/* -rf
```

#### Doxyfile

```
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8

PROJECT_NAME           = "My ToolBox"

OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./doc

INPUT                  = ./src ./include

OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = French

MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES

FILE_PATTERNS          = *.cpp \
                         *.hpp

GENERATE_HTML          = YES

EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
```

[image: The folder of the project with the doc folder open]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a target with no prerequisites, if it exists on the disk then it's considered up to date.  You have a rule:

```
doc:
        ....
```

When you run `make doc` make tries to see if the `doc` target is up to date.  Here you have a target `doc` which has no prerequisites, and it exists on the disk (you have a `doc` directory) so make considers it up to date.

If you want this `doc` target to not refer to the actual directory on the disk, you should [declare it `.PHONY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) like this:

```
.PHONY: doc
doc:
        ....
```

Now when you run `make doc` make will always run the recipe associated with that target.

Answer (score 0):

The @MadScientist answer is good. If you want to improve it further and make it incremental, you could specify dependencies of the documentation build like so:

```
doc/index.html: Doxyfile src/*.cpp include/*.hpp
    doxygen Doxyfile

.PHONY: doc
doc: doc/index.html ;
```

In this case if any of your source or header files changed, or if `Doxyfile` changed, `make` would consider documentation out of date, and rebuild it. It will also build it if doc/index.html doesn't exist, e.g. if the "doc" folder is empty.

On the other hand if your "doc/index.html" file was just generated, and nothing changed in your source code files - then nothing has to be done.